# Try to ping google, get virginmediabusiness

Tags: virtualbox, centos, routing

I'm currently trying to set up a Centos virtual machine for development work.  As it's meant for testing server side code I really don't want to have to install a desktop component and have so far only installed commandline tools.

I was having all kinds of weird network problems during setup and so I did what I usually do when that happens.  I tried pinging google.com.

I got pings back, but not from google.com!

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (62.252.232.55) 56(04) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 55.232-252-62.static.virginmediabusiness.co.uk (62.252.232.55): IMCP seq=1 ttl=59 time=13.2ms
...
```

After my initial WTF I suspect that the problem is probably down to my ISP's attempt to poach traffic from better search engines and force its customers into using its infinitely crappier one.  If I remember correctly when this happened in my main computer I had to go to a specific page in my browser and tell them that no, I didn't want their service that's worse than Google or Bing and flooded with far more adverts than either.

The thing is this VM doesn't have a GUI installed and I really really REALLY don't want to install one just so I can use a browser to tell them to go forth and multiply again.  I'm not sure but I don't think line mode browsers are going to be able to do whatever's necessary to disable this "feature" either (and I might not even be able to install one if yum is being interfered with because of this).  I am going to attempt that and see where this gets me, but in the meantime, if anybody has had experience with this problem with this or similar ISPs, any advice would most definitely be welcome.

And no, calling their tech support really isn't an option either because their tech support staff are pretty much useless for anything that can't be fixed without turning it off and on again

Comment: Lynx is a text-mode browser. You may be able to use that to load the relevant page.

Comment: Tried that, I don't think it's supported by their system.

Comment: Looks like DNS hijacking by your ISP. You might want to try changing your DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. However, be sure this does not violate your ISP's TOS before you do this—you may be contractually required to use their search engine or DNS server (so as to ensure they cannot lose this potential revenue stream).

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Linux, but if you can look at the HTTP request that goes out when you submit the form you might then be able to resend it using something like curl from linux?

Comment: Actually, I would leave that crappy ISP. An ISP is an ISP, so it should connect to the internet, and do nothing more.
You can run ' system-config-network' as root to change the dns server.

Comment: @bwDraco Yours is the correct answer and let me get up and running properly.

Comment: @davidbaumann I'm sure the OP would love that, but the odds are he's stranded with them by their monopoly. US ISPs deliberately don't compete.